# tuples for list - python

Tags: python

Organization scheme of the data in the csv file:

```
Lisbon,Madrid,600
Madrid,Paris,650
```

---

```
import csv
with open('cidades.csv', 'r') as f: # Somente r para leitura do arquivo
   read = csv.DictReader(f)
   list1 =[]
   for line in read:
       list1.append=tuple(line.values())
```

I want to store these `tuple`s all in a `list` and then I use the "distance" attribute to calculate the smallest path between two cities

It returns an error passing the tuple to the end of the list. AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

Comment: `list1.append=tuple(line.values())` ??

Comment: what is your question / on what are you stuck?

Comment: returns an error passing the tuple to the end of the list.
  AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

Comment: aaaaah `list1.append(tuple(line.values()))` then....

Comment: or `list1 = [tuple(line.values() for line in read]` in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course:

```
list1.append=tuple(line.values())
```

here you're trying to redefine the `append` method of `list` as a `tuple`. Fortunately for you, `list` members are protected against redefinition, which explains the error.

This is a typo: you should have done:

```
list1.append(tuple(line.values()))
```

better: get rid of the loop and read `list1` in one go using list comprehension:

```
with open('cidades.csv', 'r') as f:
    list1 = [tuple(line.values()) for line in csv.DictReader(f)]
```

but this approach still makes me dubious: reading the values loses infomation about the order (unless you're using Python 3.6 which uses `OrderedDict` for `csv` to fix this issue). I would drop `DictReader` and rely on the order of your csv using `csv.reader`, like this:

```
with open('cidades.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip the title line we don't need it
    list1 = [tuple(line) for line in reader]
```

Comment: how do you access the tuple values at each iteration in the list?